# Write a code to generate all pairs of numbers, the sum of whose square is equal to 100

Tags: php

Write a code to generate all pairs of numbers, the sum of whose square is equal to 100 i.e:- x^2 + y^2 = 100

Comment: are numbers should be `integer` or `float` ??

Comment: Homework done. Great job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program in C language is:

```
int num , i , j , root;
scanf ( "%d", &num );//Input the number
root = sqrt( num ); //We don't need to check the square upto input number. Just upto 
                  //Its square root
for( i = 1 ; i < root ; i++ )
{
    j = i;
    for( ; j < root ; j++ )
    {
        if( ( ( i*i ) + ( j*j ) ) == num ) //If square is equal to number
        {
            printf( "%d %d\n",i,j );      //Print the combination
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really Thanks sir, this is the easiest way I have got.

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

function getPossibleSquare($limit)
{
    $numbers = [];
    $number = 0;
    while(pow($number, 2) < $limit) {
        array_push($numbers, $number);
        $number++;
    }
    return $numbers;
}

function generateCombinations($numbers, $equals)
{
    $combinations = [];
    foreach($numbers as $x) {
        foreach($numbers as $y) {
            if( (pow($x, 2) + pow($y, 2)) == $equals ) {
                array_push($combinations, [$x, $y]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $combinations;
}

$limit = 100;

$combinations = generateCombinations( getPossibleSquare($limit), $limit );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for INT number:
$limit => 100

```
<?php
    $limit = 100;  
    $max_pair_value = ceil(sqrt($limit));

    for($i = 0; $i<=$max_pair_value; $i++){
        for($j = $i; $j<=$max_pair_value; $j++){
            $answer = pow($i,2) + pow($j, 2);  //YOUR CONDITION
            if($answer == $limit){
                $pair[] = [0=>$i, 1=>$j];
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($pair);  //UNIQUE PAIR
?>
```